# How to have a function return 2 sperate values?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function the returns BAC for both male and female sexes. The formula for BAC for my assignment is  `BAC = (drinks / Weight * R)` with R being a different value for males and females. How would I get it to return the value for both sexes?

This is the code I tried using but it doesn't work:

```
if sex =='M':
    R = 3.8
    BAC = (drinks / Weight * R) 
    BAC = BAC - (0.01 * (Duration / 40))
    return BAC
if sex == 'F':
    R = 4.5
    BAC = (drinks / Weight * R) 
    BAC = BAC - (0.01 * (Duration / 40))
    return BAC
```

I have another function in the code that does define sex, but putting that into the function seems to complicate things, so I think I need to remove the variable sex altogether, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Your code is not valid python: undefined variables and `return` outside of a function.

Comment: @Michael: It's valid Python, just incomplete and not a [mre].

Answer (score 2):

Use a tuple as a return value:

```
# we're inside a function def here
    RM = 3.8
    BACM = (drinks / Weight * RM) 
    BACM = BACM - (0.01 * (Duration / 40))
    
    RF = 4.5
    BACF = (drinks / Weight * RF) 
    BACF = BAFC - (0.01 * (Duration / 40))

    return BACM, BACF
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, returning 2 values is like returning a tuple (basically a list). This can be very useful, especially when mixed with destructuring a list.
Example:

```py
def get_bac():
    maleBAC = 50  # random number for now, replace with the math necessary
    femaleBAC = 75
    return maleBAC, femaleBAC


male, female = get_bac()
print(male)  # 50
print(female)  # 75
```

Comment: Might make it clearer to say `return maleBAC, femaleBAC`

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info). While the answer to your question is that you can return any collection type, like a `tuple`, `Sequence`, `Mapping`, or even create your own class, it is just simpler to accept the gender as a parameter to the function.